# Is there a Raspbian image with OpenCV 3 pre-installed?

Tags: opencv

After spending days trying to get OpenCV3 to install on Raspbian Stretch, always failing, I thought it would massively help if there's an image with OpenCV pre-installed, which would save several hours of compilation and debugging.

Please let me know if there is one available?

I've followed pyimagesearch links, tried to follow steps given all over the net, spent 3 days but to no avail!

Comment: this : https://medium.com/@rosbots/ready-to-use-image-raspbian-stretch-ros-opencv-324d6f8dcd96

or : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/21/raspbian-opencv-pre-configured-and-pre-installed/

Answer (score 5):

You can install opencv in a few minutes using [piwheels](https://www.piwheels.org/):

```
sudo apt install libatlas3-base libwebp6 libtiff5 libjasper1 libilmbase12 libopenexr22 libilmbase12 libgstreamer1.0-0 libavcodec57 libavformat57 libavutil55 libswscale4 libqtgui4 libqt4-test libqtcore4
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

https://blog.piwheels.org/new-opencv-builds/

Answer (score 3):

This, link may be helpfull. The image contains the last raspbian SO (Stretch), Ros and OpenCV

https://medium.com/@rosbots/ready-to-use-image-raspbian-stretch-ros-opencv-324d6f8dcd96

Answer (score 3):

Preparing a Raspberry Pi for OpenCV development is really time consuming, OpenCV takes hours to compile and a lot of other things have to be set up, so I just share my SD Card image here to speed up Raspberry OpenCV development for others. I shrank the root partition to 7GB to make it suitable for smaller SD cards. It has 300MB free space only so you better expand it to fit on the target SD card. You can do this right on your raspberry with an additional USB-SD card stick and gparted. User/pass is pi/raspberry. After startup it autologins directly to OpenBox. Right click -> Terminal emulator to open a terminal. To test and run the OpenCV examples type "workon cv" to activate the python virtual environment, go into "/home/pi/Desktop/OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master/FacialRecognition" and type "python 03_face_recognition.py" . If you have a raspberry camera installed and enabled with raspi-config, a camera window should pop up and face detection should start. For a usb camera you have to modify the scripts a little.

What does it contain

*Base System*

Raspbian Lite

*GUI*

openbox for window manager 
tint2 for taskbar 
slim for autologin 
pcmanfm for file manager 
chromium for stack overflow

*Dev Tools*

lxterminal for terminal 
vim/nano for python 
codeblocks for c/c++ development 
python for opencv development 
opencv 4.0 for computer vision 
picamera python module for the raspberry camera 
opencv face recognition examples

*Games*

Scratch, Termite, Cortex, Brawl for short rests ( enable full KMS OpenGL support in raspi-config to play them )

Download from : http://milgra.com/downloads/milgrapi/

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded an image for myself to the drive. but here, you can use this as well. this has preinstalled OpenCV and dlib in it. will require a 32 GB card because its size is around 29 GB when uncompressed. this is tested on raspberry pi 3b+. not sure about the rest of the pi's. enjoy.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cAsP2EU3066T0_047MdGDvxlXbvIgD0Q/view?usp=sharing